# CSS: Tough time imitating Whatsapp alignment in message bubble

Tags: css, react-native

I'm looking to replicate the space-efficient CSS in a whatsapp chat bubble. Specifically, you can see that when there is room remaining on the last line of a message, the time text is fit in, while when there is not, the time text appears below the body of the message. I'm in react native, but any flexbox instructions would be fantastic. 
Thanks

[image: whatsapp chat]

at the moment, I'm using a Text tag to wrap the body and the time:

```
<View style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    <Text>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>{body}</Text>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>{time}</Text>
    </Text>
</View>
```

however, im not sure how to slide the time all the way to the right of the bubble

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking for.  Can you point out what you mean by "text appears below the body of the message" and "the text fix in"?

Comment: Thank you, much clearer now.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you’re currently using that’s not working?

Comment: edited to address your comment

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the time that will "move", but the text.
You have to check if the text has more than one line, and if it doesn't has, you add margin to right, and remove margin from bottom.
The time have an absolute position.